# WatiN - Find HTML Table

Tags: watin

I´m trying to get the values of TDs inside a table using WatiN. The problem is that I´m not able to select a table by Id (because it´s missing) and three tables have the same CSS class:

table class='tablePpal' width='100%' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='1' border='0'

table class='tablePpal' width='100%' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='1' border='0'

table class='tablePpal' width='100%' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='1' border='0'

I need to select second table TDs. I tryed:

Table _table = browser.Table(Find.ByClass("tablePpal"));

Unfortunately that code does not return a collection of tables, only the first one found. How can I select the second table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.Table(Find.ByClass("tablePpal") && Find.ByIndex(1))
```

Comment: That method works great. I was also able to select the table using the ancestor method.

Table _table = (Table)browser.Link(Find.ById("btnMarca")).Ancestor("table");