# How to click a non ID java button in my c# browser?

Tags: c#, button, click, browser, watin

I have a c# program which has a web browser my program deals with java pages i want it to click a button in a page but the button has no ID or value  all i got about it is  this code :

```
  td class="submit">
  <br>
   <button class="fixedSizeBigButton" type="submit">
   </td>
```

please is there any way to click that button

and for  http://watin.sourceforge.net/   i need a code

thanks a lot

Comment: is there a way to do this with out http://watin.sourceforge.net/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button has a class name,you can find your button using class name,see this example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<td class=\"submit\"><br><button   class=\"fixedSizeBigButton\" type=\"submit\"></td>";
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement btn in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
        {
            if (btn.GetAttribute("ClassName") == "fixedSizeBigButton")
            {
                btn.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: oh thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks a lot my friend ♥
it works perfectly .
can you vote up i want to use chat ^_^

Comment: is this work with all java classes ?
check boxes buttons and all ?

Comment: +1 Great answer! I have been trying a ton of code, and this finally works!!

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://www.caffeinatedcoder.com/watin-and-the-iedevtoolbar-the-dynamic-duo-of-automated-web-testing/) link when I went looking around.

More looking around leads me to believe you need to look more into the entire `Find` class itself.  I know there are other ways to locate elements.

I'm trying to locate the documentation that will let me construct some code, since I've never actually used this before :-)  I'll update if/when I get something more.

**Update**

Looks like you aren't the only one having similar issues.  You can apparently Chain find methods.  [WatiN - Find HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638524/watin-find-html-table)  Which seems rather useful, if you know more about the button's exact location.  Using `Find.ByClass` along with something else, to try to define the button uniquely.